# insert conditional for hours

Tags: python, odoo

Good evening, could you help me in how I can put a condition so that a message comes out saying that you can not take an hour because it is already busy ?, I currently have this:

```
class reserva (models.Model):

     _name='gimnasio.reserva'

     tipo_reserva=fields.Selection([('clase','Clase'),('evaluacion','Evaluacion')])

     fecha_reserva=fields.Date()

     start_time=fields.Float()

     end_time=fields.Float()

     def fecha(self):

          if self.star_time==self.star_time:

               raise validationError('the hour is busy')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I have another question for you. you know how to configure Datetime only for hour and minutes because I only need hour and minutes but not the date.`

To configure Datetime only for hour and minutes.

```py
time = fields.Datetime("time")
custom_time = fields.Char('my_custome_time')
    @api.onchange('time')
    def _get_time(self):
        if self.time:
            for rec in self:
                # datetime value is a string like 'YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS' 
                # so just extract string from position 11 to 16
                _time = self.time[11:16]
                self.custom_time = _time
                rec.custom_time = self.custom_time
```

Comment: [if have any question, post it in chat, I'll reply when I am free](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195957/chat)

Comment: the method is perfect, thank you very much.

In the previous method change 'start_time' to 'hora_inicio' but it does not work for me now.  @api.constrains("hora_inicio","fecha")
     def _check(self):
        records = self.env["gimnasio.reserva"].search([('hora_inicio','=', self.hora_inicio), ('fecha','!=', self.fecha), ('tipo_reserva', '!=', 'evaluacion_id') ,('id', '!=', self.id)])
        if len(records) > 0:
          raise ValidationError('La evaluacion no esta disponible para esta hora')

Comment: also add the following method:
@api.constrains('hora_inicio')
     def _check_hora_inicio(self):
         if self.hora_inicio >= self.hora_termino:
          raise ValidationError('Para la reserva la hora de inicio tiene que ser mayor a la hora de termino)

Comment: but something changed that does not work for me now!

Comment: I can't see your definition of `hora_inicio` and `hora_termino`, please post it in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195957/chat). I'll reply when I'm free.

Comment: tipo_reserva=fields.Selection([('0','Clase'),('1','Evaluacion')])
     fecha=fields.Date(string="Fecha reserva")
     hora_inicio=fields.Float(string="hora inicio", computer="_hora_inicio")
     hora_termino=fields.Float(string="hora termino", computer="_hora_termino")

Comment: please post all fields and functions in the model, because your fields `hora_inicio` and `hora_termino` have attr `compute`.

Comment: BTW, `compute` not `computer`.

Comment: And, could please enter this [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195957/chat)? < click it and post your issue.

Comment: I need to understand what your model looks like to solve the issue.

Comment: I can not enter to speak in the chat because I do not have 20 reputation points but I leave my mail so you can communicate and send the model. fgonzalezmejias@hotmail.es

Comment: I think you have enough reputation to enter now.

Comment: hello, leave a message in the chat

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use strptime method from datetime module.

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt
    start_time = fields.Float()
    end_time = fields.Float()

    @api.onchange('start_time','end_time')
    def _check(self):
        records = self.env["gimnasio.reserva"].search([("day", '=', the day you want to check eg. "2019-06-13")])
        for rec in records:
            ref_start = dt.strptime(str(rec.start_time), "%H:%M")
            curr_start = dt.strptime(str(self.start_time), "%H:%M")
            if ref_start == curr_start:
                raise validationError('the hour is busy')
```

I didn't debug yet, you can try it.

`how to eliminate the default date that you added ("2019-06-13") and that any date should not have the same busy schedule?`

In this case you don't need datetime module just

```
    @api.constrains("start_time")
    def _check(self):
        # search db for any record have same start time.
        records = self.env["gimnasio.reserva"].search([('start_time ','=', self.start_time)])
        if len(records) > 0:
            raise validationError('the hour is busy')
```

Comment: how to eliminate the default date that you added ("2019-06-13") and that any date should not have the same busy schedule?

Comment: updated,and there are some useful ORM methods could help you in odoo's developer document. https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/orm.html#common-orm-methods

Comment: hello, when I use your code I get the following error Invalid field 'start_time' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: ('start_time', '=', 17.0) on gimnasio_reserva (ctx:)>", you know how to solve?

Comment: did you full copy my code? I found I append whitespace after start_time as `'start_time '`. If so you should trim it. or double check field name.

Comment: if the method worked, thank you!  I have a doubt the system is empty, I have no reservation in it.  When creating my time reservation it tells me that "hour is busy" but it is the first reservation and the system has no more data.

Comment: you can set breakpoint on line#4  `records = self.env["gimnasio.reserva"].search([('start_time ','=', self.start_time)])` to check the record.id while running.  It's wired that the db is empty but can get records. I'm confused.

Comment: while you get warning what is the value of self.start_time?

Comment: The method does not cause me an error, but it does not let me register reservations because it says "'the hour is busy"

Comment: or I guess ,for some reason, it check two times, before saving into db and after saving into db. then you should add one more condition into search to trim record itself. As `records = self.env["gimnasio.reserva"].search([('start_time','=', self.start_time),('id', '!=', self.id)])`

Comment: It is right!! It works perfectly. I have a question about the reservation class in my model, I have evaluation reservations and classes (2 types of reservations). How can I make the method work only for one type of reservation (evaluation) and not both!

Comment: class Reserva (models.Model):                                                 _name='gimnasio.reserva'
     _rec_name="id"
  tipo_reserva=fields.Selection([('Clase','Clase'),('Evaluacion','Evaluacion')])   
     fecha=fields.Date()
     start_time=fields.Float()
     end_time=fields.Float()

     alumno_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='gimnasio.alumno', string='Alumno', required=False)
     
     clase_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='gimnasio.clase', string='Clase', required=False) 

     evaluacion_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='gimnasio.evaluacion', string='Evaluacion')

Comment: Do you means only warn while tipo_reserva select `evaluacion`? It's same way: to add one more condition to search. I think you can give it a try. And then talk about the error after fail on it. This way could help you more.

Comment: search([domain]) , this topic will help you, https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/orm.html#domains

Comment: @api.constrains("start_time","fecha")
     def _check(self):
        # search db for any record have same start time.
        records = self.env["gimnasio.reserva"].search([('start_time','=', self.start_time), ('fecha','!=', self.fecha), ('domain','=' [('evaluacion_id', '!=', 'clase_id')]),('id', '!=', self.id)])
        if len(records) > 0:
          raise ValidationError('La evaluacion no esta disponible para esta hora')

Comment: I try to add the search ([domain]), but I get the following error "string indices must be integers"

Comment: Do you means only warn while tipo_reserva select evaluacion? - Yes, that's what I want to do.

Comment: search([domain]) `domain is a sets of tuple` so it should be like as`(condition 1),(condition2)`. It's form should be `('field_name', 'operator', value)` In your case, `('start_time','=', self.start_time)` is first condition, ` ('fecha','!=', self.fecha)` is second.

Comment: the correct one should be `search([('start_time','=', self.start_time), ('fecha','!=', self.fecha), ('tipo_reserva', '!=', 'evaluacion'),('id', '!=', self.id)])`

Comment: you're welcome. And I will appreciate that any useful vote for my comments.

Comment: I have another question for you.
you know how to configure Datetime only for hour and minutes because I only need hour and minutes but not the date.

Comment: Hello friendvTerrence Poe, I need to contact you, can you open a chat room please?